# Update column with text and increment value in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named *client* with the following column:

```
| Name |
 -------
|Joseph|
|Mike  |
|Tony  |
...
```

I wanna update the entire column to 'Client + increment_value'. Example:

```
| Name |
-------
|Client 1|
|Client 2|
|Client 3|
```

...

I tried first to implement a way to increment a value, but i think that it's not Postgres supported:

```
declare @i int  = SELECT ISNULL(MAX(name),0) + 1 FROM person

update person
set name  = @i , @i = @i + 1
```

Best regards,

Comment: You cannot *increment* text fields.

Comment: I was thinking about append the number to the string 'Client'

Comment: This table is screaming for a generated PK and at least 1 other column to make each row unique from the business perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that duplicate `Name` values should be consolidated:

```
select 'Client '||dense_rank() over (order by "Name") as "Name"
  from client;
```

Assuming the values in `Name` are unique, you can update in place with:

```
with scrubbing as (
  select "Name", 
         'Client '||dense_rank() over (order by "Name") as new_name
    from client
)
update client
   set client."Name" = s.new_name 
  from scrubbing s
 where s."Name" = client."Name";
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks.
Any ideia how to combine with the update?

update client
set name = (
     select 'Cliente '||dense_rank() over (order by "name") as "name"
     from person limit 1
 ) 

"limit 1" was just for test, otherwise i get "ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Best regargs

Comment: @John  Added an example.

Comment: Thank you very much